# GeoServer GWC sending 404 when geofence is activated

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-geofence

On a vanilla GeoServer 2.20.1 geowebcache is working fine. But after installing internal geofence-server as explained by the [docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/geofence-server/index.html) the seeding page `https://mydomain/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/tiger:giant_polygon` but also the demo */geoserver/gwc/demo* of a layer results in a 404 error.

[image]

The verbose logging shows:

```
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/nurc:pk50095, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/nurc:pk50095, QueryString: null'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/nurc:pk50095, QueryString: null'; against '/'
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/nurc:pk50095, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/nurc:pk50095, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/nurc:pk50095, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/nurc:pk50095, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/nurc:pk50095, QueryString: null'; against '/rest/**'
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/nurc:pk50095, QueryString: null'; against '/gwc/rest/**'
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /gwc/rest/seed/nurc:pk50095, QueryString: null with /gwc/rest/**
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/gwc/rest/seed/nurc:pk50095'; to: '/gwc/rest/seed/nurc:pk50095'  and httpMethod= GET
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [GET]
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/gwc/rest/seed/nurc:pk50095'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=true
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - returning ADMIN
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [geoserver.monitor] - Testing /gwc/rest/seed/nurc:Pk50095 for monitor filtering
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named gwc
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named gwc
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named gwc
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named gwc
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named gwc
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named gwc
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named gwc
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 WARN [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/nurc:Pk50095
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:50 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:51 TRACE [platform.resource] - polling contents of /var/local/geoserver/gwc-layers
geoserver_1  | 03 Dec 08:32:51 TRACE [platform.resource] - delta computed in 4ms for /var/local/geoserver/gwc-layers
```

Of course I've setup an allow all rule:

[image]

The rest is standard, inbuilt h2 store. No custom config.

It looks I forgot something obvious. What could go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

gwc.context.suffix=gwc in geofence-server.properties fixed it for me